# Self-Promoting Data Types

Tags: c, types

I read through the method for using variadic functions in C at http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Macros.html#Argument-Macros

However, I was unable to grasp the meaning of self-promoting data types. What are they & how are they different from non-self-promoting data types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf); "self-promoting" types are those which promote to themselves when the *default argument promotions* (§6.5.2.2 paragraph 6, referencing the integer promotions described in §6.3.1.1) are applied.

My reading of the `va_arg` definition (§7.15.1.1) is that this limitation *is* implied by the standard.  The relevant part is in paragraph 2:

> [...] or if *type* is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according 
>   to the default argument promotions) [...]

which is quite clear about the type of the actual next argument being promoted, but I read as not saying anything about *type* being promoted.  (I think the "(as promoted...)" clause is just a reminder that default argument promotions are performed on the trailing arguments when a varargs function is called.)

This item in the list of undefined behaviour in §J.2 supports this reading:

> — The `va_arg` macro is invoked when there is no actual next argument, or with a 
>   specified type that is not compatible with the promoted type of the actual next 
>   argument, with certain exceptions (7.15.1.1).

(although yes, I know,  Annex J is "informative" rather than "normative"...).

In which case: `va_arg(ap, float)` (for example) cannot be valid - *type* in that case is `float`, but the promoted type of the actual next argument cannot possibly be `float` (a `float` argument would be promoted to `double`).

Comment: Is there any particular reason for this restriction? Perhaps something to do with the `va_arg` implemetation?

Comment: @crypto: I suspect that Zack is right (see his response to Jens); there isn't an obvious way to find the default argument promotion of a given type without special help from the complier, so this allows for an implementation of `va_arg(ap, type)` which works without such help.  (e.g. keep a byte pointer to the current argument on the stack in `ap`; then `va_arg` might be some hideous macro which moves to the next argument by casting that to `type *`, incrementing the `type *` pointer, and casting back to a byte pointer.)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a glibc restriction, the C standard doesn't have that.

The idea behind this is that integer types that have so-called "conversion rank" smaller than `int` are automatically promoted to `signed` or `unsigned` `int`. A va_arg function then finds such a wider argument. The `va_arg` macro must then first read the wider argument of type `int`, say, and then cast it back to the original type.

(Same holds for `float` w.r.t to `double`.)

For the unaware programmer this can have surprising result, so I agree with the idea that this should be avoided. The description you are citing seems to imply that it is imposed to not use a small type. This is bogus and as I said not in alignment with the standard. On the other hand if you write code as they suggest you will never have a portability issue with that because this is a restriction and not an extension.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge Matthew is correct and you are wrong; this restriction *is* in C99 at least.  If you think about it, it would be very, very difficult -- I won't swear to _impossible_, but the C standard has generally avoided placing merely _difficult_ requirements on implementations -- to do a "traditional" implementation of `va_arg` (one that does not expand to a compiler intrinsic) without this restriction, given that argument promotion happens in the caller.

Comment: @Zack: lets say the wording is at least ambiguous, the scope of the "as promoted..." is not clear. But I don't agree with you that allowing for narrow types puts *much* burden on the implementation. They'd just have to check for the narrow types, read an argument of the promoted type (an implementation has to know how to find that type, anyhow) and cast the value back to the narrow type.

Comment: That would be an easy thing to do *from a compiler intrinsic*.  The traditional implementation of `va_arg` does not have access to any such conveniences; it does everything with (technically undefined) core language expressions.  As C does not include any way of doing metaprogramming on types, I don't think you could "find an argument of the promoted type and cast back to the narrow type" using only core language expressions.